# How to show content for different or all categories?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page called "categories.php". I use it to show different content for different categories.

Example:

```
mysite.com/categories.php?cat=dance (shows dancing content)
mysite.com/categories.php?cat=sing (show singing content)
Etc...
```

The database has two different tables:

```
Categories
categories_id
categories_title

Categories_content
cat_content_id
categories_id
categories_text
categories_image
```

So far so good. But now the problem I'm facing. Let's say I want to show a content on all the categories. Usually I'll have to add the same content for all the categories one by one. But I think there should be a way to add it only once and show it on all the pages.

I forgot to mention that I use a form with a dropdown menu where the categories are list for which I would like to add the content.

Any ideas how to do this? Do I have to use multiple SQL queries to achieve this?

Maybe I'm just making it hard for myself and there is an easy solution for this.

Thanks in advance.
mw

Comment: You use a query with a join.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean? I know how to use join, but when adding the content the form has a dropdown menu where I can choose the category for the content I want to add. Maybe I should have written that in my above post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a new category called "all" or something, you can implement this in the query.

So instead of:

```
SELECT * FROM Categories JOIN [...] WHERE categories_title = '{$_GET['cat']}'
```

Use:

```
SELECT * FROM Categories JOIN [...] WHERE categories_title = '{$_GET['cat']}' OR categories_title = 'all'
```

Then on a category listing, filter out "all".

There are many ways of doing this, mine might not be the best but it's the best off the top of my head.

Comment: I think I missed the context, Lazadon's answer is better if you are trying to display literally ALL content.  I interpreted it as you wanted exclusive content on all categories.

Comment: No I was thinking about the same solution you provided, I just needed to see if there were other options I could choose from. I think I will implement this, as it is the most simple form at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to use SQL without a where clause. It should return all id's regardless of categories_id.

```
Select cat_content_id from categories_content;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Lazadon, but I need to filter. I don't want "dancing" content in the "singing" content page, that's why I use the filter.